# Nothing displays when using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I followed this [tutorialpoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_router.htm) and it works well when all the code in `main.js`. But if i put my code in separated files, it doesn't work:

**app.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'react-router';

export default class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/Home">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/About">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/Contact">Contact</Link></li>
            </ul>

           {this.props.children}
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export class Home extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Home...</h1>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export class About extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>About...</h1>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export class Contact extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>Contact...</h1>
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router';
import App, { Home, About, Contact } from './app.jsx';

ReactDOM.render((

    <Router history = {browserHistory}>
        <Route path = "/" component = {App}>
            <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
            <Route path = "home" component = {Home} />
            <Route path = "about" component = {About} />
            <Route path = "contact" component = {Contact} />
        </Route>
    </Router>

), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Maybe `export` not works ? In my console, i have some warnings:

> index.js:9169 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null,
>   undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM
>   elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render
>   method of `App`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are importing `Link` is not correct.

```
import Link from 'react-router';
```

should be

```
import { Link } from 'react-router'
```

Comment: Thanks ! I forgot it.